# Not for Cleithrophobics / Claustrophobics?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

Find out the missing alphabetical letter by linking to the title of this puzzle:

A **:** d  **: :** B **:** **?**

One unique solution exists.

Comment: ^vote with a note: You love language! This puzzle would be clearer, though, if the words in the title were defined, or at least have definition links, in the statement itself. Signed – language lover

Comment: cleithrophobia: fear of being trapped. claustrophobia: fear of confined places

Comment: @humn, persons afraid of either being getting trapped / persons afraid of closed/confined places - are the literal meanings of the words in the title and they have to do something with the given puzzle!. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that the answer is

> g
> Claustrophobia is the fear of confined spaces, so the 'A' has one confined space as does the 'd'. The capital B has two enclosed spaces, and the cursive lowercase 'g' also has two enclosed spaces.

Comment: Kudos, correct, as mentioned, when 'g' is written with two spaces (which I can not print /type now :(   )

Comment: This answer could also mention [Roman/looptail](http://www.disruptiveconversations.com/2007/11/the-curious-cas.html) $\rm g$, displayable here by entering `$\rm g$`

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> o

My reasoning is that

> Each item in the pair should be a letter with an enclosed area (lower case examples are a, b, d, e, g, o, p, and q. upper case  are A, B, D, O, P, Q, and R).  However, since the upper case B has no "legs" coming off of the enclosed space, then I would assume the solution from the lower case would have to be the same).

Comment: This is probably a wide miss on the intended answer, but indicating that there is one unique solution leads me to believe that this is it, since it meets all of the OP's criteria.

Comment: Title indicates closed spaces nice

Comment: @APrough, well, got the crux of the puzzle correctly, but _not_ the provided answer!

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay - as I said, I was not sure that this was the answer, but it is an answer that fits the question.  This leads me to believe that this is too broad...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

> e

Why?

- I took the question as a "literal," `A:d::B:?` ("A is-to d, as B is-to ?")

> A:d => {(A + 26) + 3} (to lower case)

so

> {(B + 26) + 3} => e

And that character has tight spaces. In fact, it looks like a closing character.

*Edits*

And it's the only character that has that look. Also one of the criterion.

Comment: You've completely ignored the title, though...